# How can I animate a DOM element using transitions with dynamic values?

Tags: jquery, animation, css, webkit

I've been trying to animate DOM elements using [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) alone, since I've read they're better in many forms. However, My question is simple, **Is there a way to pass dynamic values for an animation using transitions?** I basically don't know how to do this, ie. I can only animate a DOM element by adding a class with fixed values as seen in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/P6zUw/) (Works well on webkit browsers)

As you can see in the CSS class:

```
.motion {
  left: 300px;
  top: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

... The values for the animation are static, And I would like to know **How can I pass parameters to a transition during runtime?**, *(ie. a different value for left. for example)*

I've tried to do it with jQuery through the **.css()** method like this:

```
function clickButton() {
  $("#button1").click(function(event) {
    $("#square").css( { 'left': '30', 'top': '100' });          
  });
}​
```

But for some reason the transition doesn't get triggered. Why?

All help is immensely appreciated!

Comment: You should like [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) :) CSS3 transitions with `animate`-like API with a fallback to JS when CSS3 is not supported.

Comment: Awesome suggestion! Really Awesome. But, for the sake of learning, Do you think it's possible to do what I ask?, anyways, do you know If transit supports the webkit easing functions? This is My main reason to go with Transitions in the 1st place.

Comment: You mean [those](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/#item_18)? Read the entire page, there are a lot of examples but it's worth it :)

Comment: Yep. those ones! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, since your comments show that you like it, here is your answer:

Use [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/).

It supports easing functions as you wish.

It has an `animate`-like API, and it can fallback to `animate` when CSS3 transitions are not supported.

Comment: Yes!, really neat plug-in. However, I'm still looking into it at the moment before I provide you with my veredict, Thank you Florian!

Comment: Ok, I think I'm sticking to the Transit plug-in, I'm absolutely digging it, and it certainly is the most convenient cross-browser suggestion I've seen in some time. and I won't be re-inventing the wheel which is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Animate.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$("#square").animate({'left':'30px','top':'100px' }, "slow");
```

Comment: Well, of course I could use animate. But, like I said, I need/want to make transitions work. One reason is that in that way I can take advantage of the easing built-in functions. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery 1.6+ then you can try this to get animating behavior using `.css()` method.

```
function clickButton() {
  $("#button1").click(function(event) {
    $("#square").css( { 'left': '+=30', 'top': '+=100' });          
  });
}​
```

From jQuery docs

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to
>   .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to
>   increment or decrement the current value.

Comment: All right! This works, BUT... what is really weird is that, for the += operator to work I still need to add a class prior to calling the .css() method on the element. The following two steps work, but not alone.
ie. 1. $("#square").addClass("motion"); 2. $("#square").css( { 'left': '+=30', 'top': '+=100' });

Comment: Because it needs the initial value or else it will get the default which I guess must be 0.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm asking because if you put those initial values (top, left) set to 0 in the #square css selector itself, still doesn't work. This is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your point correctly, you want the transitions to use the value/values by the way of adding it/them to current value/value pairs: if so you should give the below method a try;

```
function clickButton() {
  $("#button1").click(function(event) {
    $("#square").css( { 'left': '+=' + 30, 'top': '+=' + 100 });
  });
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not paying attention, but I don't see anywhere a definition of transition properties, such as duration, easing, etc... I assume you have these on your CSS somewhere? If not, the thing won't work.

You need to set 2 definitions: one for the transition itself, the other for the attributes you want transformed. It's my pet peeve about CSS3 spec, that they have this convoluted way of transforming and transitioning. It's really ill-conceived.

Comment: Well, for what you have just stated, I believe an example would be great, because I don't quite understand what you're saying. As far as I'm concerned I have both of the requirements you mention. Check out my jsFiddle example and then tell me what you think.